# This footer class becomes broken whenever adding a new class to the css file

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an HTML page which has a CSS file attached. I have a footer class, defining the footer of the different pages. Whenever I add a new class above the footer class it is completely ignored. (The contents of the footer will then move to the top of the page, with no background colour whatsoever). The rest of the CSS does not seem to be affected by this. Whenever I remove the newly added class it will work again. Does anyone know what goes wrong here?

I have a HTML page within an environment that runs on a really old version of IE4 version. I have no choice in my IDE, so I can't upgrade to a newer IE version. 
The CSS has grown quite large.
I found that sometimes, moving the footer class up it works again, but then later on, when adding a new class I'll have to move it again.

Footer class (only class that affects the footer):

```
.footer{
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    position: fixed;
    border-top: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    WIDTH: 100%; 
    HEIGHT: 45px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Example of a class I add that breaks the footer class:

```
button.error:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #E95185;
}
```

I do not expect the defining of a hover property for a button class to break the footer class. 
Also, maybe good to know, the footer does not contain a button with the error class

Comment: This is my first ever question on stackoverflow, if I can do anything to make it more clear, please let me know!

Comment: oof, IE4. Can't speak to IE4 specifically, but sometimes in IE I've had to do a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5) before I see my CSS changes. Also, have a look at the Developer Tools (F12) to see what CSS is or isn't being applied

Comment: Nothing in the provided CSS looks like a problem. As @Paulie_D commented, if you can provide a complete reproducible example might help us help you. Perhaps add the HTML of the footer? The suggestion from Jay is also a very good one. Can you use the dev tools and see what CSS is being cancelled, or if the class for the footer is even being seen by the browser, either of these cases will point to different problems and solutions.